# Can't get currentime Soundcloud API JS API

Tags: javascript, soundcloud, soundmanager2

```
<script src="//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk-2.0.0.js"></script>
```

and

```
SC.stream("/tracks/" + trackid, {
    autoPlay: true,
    whileplaying: function() {
        console.log(position);
    },
    onfinish: function() {
        // alert here
    }
}, function(sound) {
    SC.sound = sound;
});
```

while pleying or after ended, i don;t get any console message... how come?

Comment: Got a link to some doco showing the `whileplaying` option? I can't see it anywhere

Comment: its' in the soundmanager2 docs... i thought it was doable...